# custom config option for a specific attribute

Tags: attributes

I have an attribute in Magento.  For this and only this attribute, I would like to have a new configuration option, similar to "Use in Quick Search" or "Allow HTML Tags on Frontend" for example.

The new option is only relevant to a specific attribute and the value must be retrievable with the attribute when it is loaded.

Is this possible?  If so how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those "attribute attributes" are derived from the `catalog_eav_attribute` table and are pretty well hidden by logic embedded in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` class. I can't see a justification for having to rewrite the classes/logic involved with saving this value or for filtering the attribute admin view to handle this sole attribute.

I think that the best approach is to use two attributes, one for the value, and one to switch the behavior. You could then use a custom backend model or frontend model to check the value of the switching attribute.